# Batch Script - Pull folders with wildcard

Tags: batch-file, pdf, command-line

I am writing a small BAT file that will recurse through over 200 folders and mark PDF files in certain folders as obsolete. The folder layout is consistent:

```
Main Directory
>Top Folder
>>User Forms
>>>Obsolete
>>Other Forms
>>>Obsolete
```

I have the part of the script that will place the PDF watermark on the PDF file but I am having trouble selecting only the folders that I need. I need to be able to pull only forms under the `User Forms>Oboslete` folder and not include the `Other Forms>Obsolete`. My current code pulls a bunch of extra files and Echos back folders that don't exist.

```
@echo off
CD \Test Directory
for /D /r %%G in ("\*Forms\Obsolete") Do (
    echo %%G
) 
cd \
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: What happens if you change `\*Forms` to `\User*Forms`?

Comment: I am not understanding why you need the wildcard at all?

Comment: I need the wildcard because the `User Forms` folder sometimes has different formatting but it always ends with "Forms" .

Comment: Does it always start with `User`?